# How to install default packages which are available after fresh installed OS(Ubuntu 20.4LTS)

Tags: apt

Basically the problem is i ran

```
sudo apt purge <some_package (i guess it was libsound2)>
```

and selected `y`,the problem is that it removed so many packages that was important(now i don't have the dock,gnome extension native connecter and so many),
so my question is that is there any way to install all default packages which comes along with freshly installed OS.

I tried `resetter`,but it was very sloppy,so stopped it

*as I'm new to linux,please explain the answer in comments*

Comment: Hello. First thing there is no Ubuntu version called 20.4 Second never use the y option especially as a new user, if you had not it would have warned you of what was being removed and you could have stopped it. At this point I recommend a fresh install.

Comment: What package did you purge and what other packages were removed? Also, please tell us what commands you have run trying to fix this.  Without this information it will be hard to know what went wrong.  If you can't remember and you are "new to Linux", you may find that it is easier for you to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 1):

When packages that are part of the default Ubuntu desktop are removed, the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop` is also removed. That metapackage is a package that depends on all the packages that are default for an Ubuntu desktop.

Thus, to restore all default packages of the Ubuntu desktop, reinstalling it should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```